# Updated Ruby, Can't Run Anything Now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

Using RVM.  Updated from ruby 1.9.2-p290 to 1.9.3-p194.

`bundle install` works fine.

When I try to run any rails task I am getting an error:

```
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:csbb Tyler$ rails c --sandox
/Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `rescue in rescue in block in require': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/Tyler/Development/Rails/csbb/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'turkee', :git => "https://github.com/workmaster2n/turkee.git", ref: '04da1de00ac02cff33341fa677ab2dd9212d4086'
gem 'yettings'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'rest-client'

gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '0.11.30.pre10'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.17.beta14'

group :development do

  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'

  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'thin'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'fakeweb'
end

group :production do

end
```

application.rb (line 13 is: `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))`):

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module WeaponXO
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.csbb = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    # config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

If I comment out line 13 of `application.rb`, I get this error (expected):

```
/Users/Tyler/Development/Rails/csbb/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Tyler/Development/Rails/csbb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

devise.rb

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "support@weaponxo.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # Automatically apply schema changes in tableless databases
  config.apply_schema = false

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:token]` will
  # enable it only for token authentication.
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. "Application" by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments.
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  # config.pepper = "414a4a386818bbd8897a8a083af56bd752a4e17d7daf490c598fae61d210ca5695d871fbbed21e9070b99804c7a52ff7c0227793cf925678ccf71d3112fd09d8"

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming his account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming his account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming his account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exctly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # If true, uses the password salt as remember token. This should be turned
  # to false if you are not using database authenticatable.
  config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # :secure => true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.cookie_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length. Default is 6..128.
  # config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # an one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  # config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Configure sign_out behavior.
  # Sign_out action can be scoped (i.e. /users/sign_out affects only :user scope).
  # The default is true, which means any logout action will sign out all active scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end
end
```

**FIXED**

Something happened with my install of ruby 1.9.3.  Read to update RVM before installing new versions of ruby (http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/11/26/fixing-the-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-error-with-nokogiri/).  From that page:

```
rvm update head #I did rvm get stable
rvm --force install 1.9.3
gem install bundle
```

Did I forget to update something along the way?

Comment: what is `config/application.rb:13`? this looks more like a problem with your project than ruby/rails.

Comment: Updated question, noticed it may be something with devise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something happened with my install of ruby 1.9.3. Read to update RVM before installing new versions of ruby (http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/11/26/fixing-the-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-error-with-nokogiri/). From that page:

```
rvm update head #I did rvm get stable
rvm --force install 1.9.3
gem install bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle.require makes sure all gems installed are imported when your app runs.  If you comment it out, add `require "devise"`

Answer (score 0):

run

```
 gem update
```

comment the below line from config/development.rb

```
 config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

and add

```
    config.assets.compress = false
    config.assets.debug = true
```

have a look into asset pipeline, if you do want to take an advantage though it's optional. As i see asset related gems present in your gem file so suggested some changes to me made. Create app/assets and directory and move the javascripts,stylesheets,images from public folder.